# No value for the dropdownlist when my form is submitted

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I try to use a dropdownlist in my view for showing a list of authors (users). I'm able to populate this dropdown and see the content in my view. When submitting my form, I debug my action in my controller and when inspecting my model, the value of the field associated with my dropdown is null.

Here is my action controller (before showing my view):

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        IEnumerable<User> authors = m_AccountBusiness.GetAllUsers();

        PageCreateViewModel viewModel = new PageCreateViewModel
        {
            PageToCreate = new PageFullViewModel(),
            Authors = authors.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.UserName, Value = x.UserID.ToString() })
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Here is (a portion of) my view:

```
@model MyBlog.ViewModels.PageCreateViewModel

<h3>Create</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PageToCreate.PageID)

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PageToCreate.Title)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PageToCreate.Title, new { @class = "titleValue" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PageToCreate.Title)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">  
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PageToCreate.Author)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">      
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PageToCreate.Author, Model.Authors, "Please select...")    
</div>
```

Here is my PageCreateViewModel:

```
public class PageCreateViewModel
{
    public PageFullViewModel PageToCreate { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys. I finally found my error: it is not Author the right property to bind to, it must be AuthorID !!

```
<div class="editor-field">           
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PageToCreate.AuthorID, Model.Authors, "Please select...")         
</div>
```

Thanks anyway.

Comment: LOL...you know what, this was my very first thought, but then i thought it's taken for granted thing and you must have cross checked....anyways good luck

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an extra string property to your PageCreateViewModel. In this property we will store the selected value. Lets say it's name is "Author". Edit: I noticed you have a property for it in your model but give it a try like this.

The dropdownlist filling needs to look like this on your view.

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Author", Model.Authors)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it doesn't work. I still have no value back in my controller for the dropdown.

Comment: @Bronzato And the other values from your model are filled correctly on return?